# ModuleMap: How can I set a relative path for the umbrella header?

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I am working with the Swift Package Manager. I have a project which I can successfully build via "swift build". I have created an Xcode project via  "swift package generate-xcodeproj". When I open the project in Xcode it builds successfully.

The Xcode project includes two modules A and B.

Module A has the following map:

```
module ModuleA {
    umbrella header "/Users/Robert/Temp/MyProject/Sources/ModuleA/include/ModuleA.h"
    link "ModuleA"
    export *
}
```

Module B depends upon A and has the following import:

```
import ModuleA
```

So far so good; everything builds successfully. Now I want to change the module map so that it uses a relative path, such as:

```
module ModuleA {
    umbrella header "ModuleA.h"
    link "ModuleA"
    export *
}
```

However, when I do that I cannot get Module B to build: Error - Umbrella header 'ModuleA.h' not found. I have tried everything that I can think of in Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Header Search Paths and User Header Search Paths. I've found similar issues online, here and elsewhere, and have tried what I read but so far no go.

This has reached the hair pulling stage. Any advice will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is you're modifying the generated modulemap. Create a modulemap file at `/Users/Robert/Temp/MyProject/Sources/ModuleA/include/module.modulemap` containing:

```
module ModuleA {
    umbrella header "ModuleA.h"
    link "ModuleA"
    export *
}
```

Run `$ swift package clean` to remove the old generated modulemap in `.build` directory and `$ swift build` to confirm that the custom modulemap works.
Then delete the generated Xcode project and re-generate it.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ankit! That worked. And, if you could shed some light on why it worked that would be great. I assume that having the module map in place when  the `swift package generate-xcodeproj` command ran caused the project to be generated with settings appropriate for a relative path in the module map. But, I should have been able to tweak the project manually if only I knew how, yes? [The vastness of xcode's build settings is so daunting]